# Filter customer collection by custom attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-attributes, customer-attribute

I created a custom attribute for customer and would like to filter my collection through it.

My UpgradeData:

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.6', '<')) {

    $attributesInfo = [
        'celular'  => [
        'label'    => 'Celular',
        'type'     => 'varchar', // can be static too
        'input'    => 'text',
        'unique' => true,
        'position' => 90,
        'visible'  => true,
        'required' => true,
        'system'   => 0, // Important otherwise attribute is not seen as custom attribute
    ],
];

    foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
    }

    foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode);
        $attribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer']
        );
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

My Collection:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection'); 
        $customer = $customerObj->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('celular',$username)
        ->load()->getData();
```

Even though I am attaching a value to this field, no customer is found, what should I do?

--EDIT!

Images database:
[image: eav_attribute]

[image: customer_entity_varchar]

Answer (score 5):

Check the value of `$username`

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection'); 
$customer = $customerObj->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('celular',$username)
        ->load();
echo $customer->getSelect()->__toString();die;
```

Please check query string.

Comment: I have checked and all information is correct in their respective tables. I edited the question with the images for you to check. Do you have any other tips? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use the ObjectManager, use the constructor:

```
<?php 
    namespace Vendor\Module\Block; 
    class ClassName {    
       protected $_productCollectionFactory;
        
       public function __construct(
           \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory 
            $productCollectionFactory     
       )
       {    
           $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
       }
    
       public function getProductCollection()
       {
         $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
         $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
         $collection->addAttributeToFilter('celular', ['eq' => $username ]);
         return $collection;
      }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It worked for me couple of months ago.

```
$replydb = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Module\Model\Yourmodel')->getCollection();
$replydb->addFieldToFilter('status', 'Approved');
$replycoll = $replydb->getData();
```

Comment: I already tested it and it did not work too, I believe that due to being using the custom attribute of the customer. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer'); 

$customerData = $customerObj->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('celular',$username);

foreach($customerData as $customer)
{
    $customer->getData();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check query.

Check the value of `$username`

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection'); 
$customer = $customerObj->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('celular',$username)
        ->load();
echo $customer->getSelect()->__toString();die;
```